# Godot - Loading a Saved Game

Tags: game-development, godot

I am trying to create a C# script to save and load the saved games in Godot. I have organized the information of each node (each node that will be saved) in a dictionary (one dictionary is created for each node that will saved) and all the information is saved in a txt document with a format like “gamesaved.txt”.

The system is saving the information without problem in the Project Data folder. The problem is that when I want to load the game saved, Godot appears to have problems to open the File. I use something like this in my “load method”:

`saveGame.Open("user://savegame.text", File.ModeFlags.ReadWrite)`

and in the next line I use

`While (saveGame.GetPosition() < saveGame.GetLen())`

to start to read the file and use the information of the dictionaries but system says ERROR!` And says:

`“get_position: File must be opened before use”`

It appears that the system doesn’t recognize that the File has been opened in the previous line with `saveGame.Open()`

Do you have any idea what the open method could not be working?

Comment: My guess: A typo in the file name. Edit: the Open method returns, it probably is returning an error code (0 means no error), you can print it to check.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I change the extension format of the saving archive to .save from .txt and now the while runs but the data is not what was saved, it is different

Comment: Hi, I'd like to help but would be good to see some code rather than just a description so it will be much clearer to see what might be going wrong